# Cisco IOS: How is it possible to break with default config register of 0x2102

Tags: cisco, ios

The default config register of an IOS device is 0x2102. The table [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps133/products_tech_note09186a008022493f.shtml) clearly states that 0x0100 signifies "Ignore Break," and that the default config register employs these options:

```
Ignores break
Boots into ROM if initial boot fails
9600 console baud rate default value for most platforms
```

In practice, and per Cisco's [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps221/products_password_recovery09186a0080094773.shtml), you are able to break the startup of a device with the default config register (mainly for bypassing/resetting passwords), so what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break can always be sent during the first 60 seconds of the bootstrap process, regardless of the configuration setting.

Comment: What is the point of the flag then? I can't find this documented anywhere, but breaking obviously works, so this must be the reason.

Comment: The point of the flag is to allow you to disable break during normal operation of the router.